# python getting a specific attribute from a list of objects

Tags: python

I have a python array of objects

```
class ball(self, size, color, name):
  self.size = size
  self.color = color
  self.name = name
```

then a user will inputs a name and an attribute via the command line. For example a user could input  "name1" and then "color" or "weirdName" then "size"... I then want to find the object based on the name and print get either the color object or the size object. Can I do it like this or will I need to use a switch case?

Thanks

Comment: Python has no switch case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do two different things here.

First, you want to get a particular ball by name. For that, gnibbler already gave you the answer.

Then, you want to get one of the ball's attributes by name. For that, use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
the_ball = next(b for b in list_of_balls if b.name == sys.argv[1])
the_value = getattr(the_ball, sys.argv[2])
print('ball {}.{} == {}'.format(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], the_value)
```

Also, your `class` definition is wrong:

```
class ball(self, size, color, name):
  self.size = size
  self.color = color
  self.name = name
```

You probably meant for this to be the `__init__` method inside the `ball` class, not the `class` definition itself:

```
class ball(object):
  def __init__(self, size, color, name):
    self.size = size
    self.color = color
    self.name = name
```

However, you may want to reconsider your design. If you're accessing attributes dynamically by name more often than you're accessing them directly, it's usually better just to store a `dict`. For example:

```
class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, size, color, name):
        self.name = name
        self.ball_props = {'size': size, 'color': color}

list_of_balls = [Ball(10, 'red', 'Fred'), Ball(20, 'blue', 'Frank')]

the_ball = next(b for b in list_of_balls if b.name == sys.argv[1])
the_value = the_ball.ball_props[sys.argv[2]]
```

Or you may even want to inherit from `dict` or `collections.MutableMapping` or whatever, so you can just do:

```
the_value = the_ball[sys.argv[2]]
```

Also, you may want to consider using a `dict` of balls keyed by name, instead of a list:

```
dict_of_balls = {'Fred': Ball(10, 'red', 'Fred'), …}
# ...

the_ball = dict_of_balls[sys.argv[1]]
```

If you've already built the `list`, you can build the `dict` from it pretty easily:

```
dict_of_balls = {ball.name: ball for ball in list_of_balls}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is exactly one match, you can do this:

```
the_ball = next(b for b in list_of_balls if b.name == ???)
```

If there are multiple then you can get a list:

```
the_balls = [b for b in list_of_balls if b.name == ???]
```

If you are primarily looking up balls by their name, you should keep them in a dictionary instead of a list

To retrieve an attribute by name use `getattr`

```
getattr(the_ball, "size")
```

Doing this can be  a bad idea

```
getattr(the_ball, user_input)
```

what if user_input is `"__class__"` or something else you didn't expect?

If you only have a few possibilities it's better to be explicit

```
if user_input == "size":
    val = the_ball.size
elif user_input in ("colour", "color"):
    val = the_ball.color
else:
    #error
```

Comment: +1. But I think (although I'm not sure) that this only answers the first half of his question; he _also_ wants to get an attribute of `the_ball` by name. So the full answer is something like your statement, followed by `the_attr = getattr(the_ball, user_given_attr_name)`.

Comment: yes, but then i just want to output one of the values, either size or color based on what the user entered

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, you need to get a particular ball from a list of balls, based on the value of an attribute. A solution would be:

```
attribute_value = sys.argv[1]
attribute_name = sys.argv[2]
matching_balls = [ball_item for ball_item in list_balls if \
     getattr(ball_item, attribute_name) == attribute_value]
```